# Advice for categorizing content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, ubercart

I'm new to Drupal 7 and UberCart and loving it.
I'm working on a site that is automotive based and am having a problem wrapping my head around the catalog.
I have 4 different parent catagories, then year/make/model and part category.  A product can be anywhere and belong to multiple categories.

Right now I have a vocabulary that contains parent category/make/model/part category and another that contains year.

I need the menu to work like

- Parent Category 1

  - Make 1

    - model 1

      - year

        - sub-cat
    - model 2
      - year

        - sub-cat
  - Make 2

    - model 1

      - year

        - sub-cat
    - model 2

      - year

        - sub-cat

Am I making this too complicated?
The sub-cats would be unique to the Parent Category but make/model/year could belong to any Parent Category and subcat.

Can anybody give me any advice?  Thanks in advance.

*edit* I guess I'm asking If I put year make model together in a vocabulary and Parent Category and subcat together in a vocabulary (which I think would work well), how can I incorporate that into UberCart catalog menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Drupality was right...It does require custom coding.
I installed [Multi Term Views](http://drupal.org/project/tf_views) which will allow nodes to be filtered that contain different, multiple taxonomies from different vocabularies.
So you could have a filtered view at `taxonomy/term/27+35` which will show all nodes in term id 27 and 35 or you can have `taxonomy/term/27,35` which will show all nodes that are exclusively in both 27 and 35.  After that was set up I just wrote a custom menu and put it in a block in the sidebar.
So I have 3 vocabularies that are Year, Make/Model, and Type.  Make/Model is two terms deep. 
Not the best solution - but if a highly customized menu is needed then apparently this is what must be done.

Thanks @Drupality for your help.